# Image display error on Github pages - Jekyll used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages

I want to host a simple blog site with Github pages, using Jekyll. In a post I want to display images. For this, I added an `image.html` file, inside `_includes` folder, in the root of the project directory.

**I built a HTML structure in the image.html file, like so:**

```
<figure class="image" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ritobrato{{include.baseurl}}/gh-pages/_posts" alt="{{ include.description }}">
<div style="padding-top: 10px"></div>
<figcaption>{{ include.description }}</figcaption></figure>
```

**Next, I added a new markdown file for a post in the `_posts` directory, in the root. I'm trying to include  an image in the .md post file like so:**

`{% include image.html url="/images/trek1.jpg" description="This is a trek image" %}`

**However, after commit and code push to GitHub repo, GitHub pages fails to display the image.**
[Click here to see the image display error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yibh1.png). **Link to my code on Github repo:-** https://github.com/Ritobrato/testBlog

After reading all similar questions on stackoverflow, it seems to be a file linking issue. Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute on your `img` tag looks problematic (doesn't point to an image or use `include.url`):

```
src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ritobrato{{include.baseurl}}/gh-pages/_posts"
```

I can't be sure where you want to point this, but since this is a Jekyll site and you are passing `url` to your include, I'd say it should be:

```
src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ include.url }}"
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't need to use a `figure` element, you could add the image within your Markdown file rather than using an include:

```
![This is a trek image]({{ site.baseurl }}/images/trek1.jpg)
```

Comment: Hello @Ross thanks for your help. However, still can't display image from Github repo but it works locally. Everything is perfect except the image breaks.

Comment: Looks like your image extension is uppercase - so you need to rename that or change it in the markdown to `![This is a trek image]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/trek1.JPG)`

Comment: Hello @Ross! So, I figured it out. Turns out I was working on gh-pages branch and so my files suffered from a routing issue. Solved it with `{{'/path/to/my/image.jpg' | relative_url}}` this filter solved the issue. On master branch `/path/to/my/image.jpg` route solves the issue. For both these I put an image.html file in the _includes dir, and called it in the md. However, directly calling the image from md is not working, no idea why!